# Maybe Stuck Pedal Triangle with geometry problem

Tags: geometry

Suppose $P$ is any point within an acute-angled triangle,Let $X,Y,Z$ be the feet of the perpendiculars from $P$ onto the sides $BC,CA,AB$ respectively. and $U,V,W$ be where $AP,BP,CP$ meet the sides $BC,AC,AB$ respectively.

show that：
$$|UV|+|UW|+|VW|\ge |XY|+|XZ|+|YZ|$$
[image]

This problem is from  New Zealand 2015 TST exam ,It is said no one solved it in the olympiad. Everyone got 0 point.Background Pedal Triangle  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PedalTriangle.html

Comment: The second term on the RHS should be XZ right?

Comment: Is the error present in the given problem of the Olympiad ?